# Django How do i determine what arguments are missing?

Tags: python, django, testing

Trying to access part of code by get request and receiving this error 
**NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'homepage' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []** looked around for help and i think its that am missing some arguments.
here is request am using in my test

```
req = self.client.get('/password/reset/')
```

and the code it leads to is as:

```
class PasswordResetEmailView(FormView):
   template_name = 'temp/password_reset.html'
   form_class = PasswordResetForm
   success_url = 'password_reset_ok'

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      form = self.get_form(self.form_class)
      return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

any guidance ?

Comment: You need to show us the code where you use `homepage` and also the related url definitions.

Comment: in this part of app there is no homepage usage can you explain error a bit so i can find a direction to look for cause ?

Comment: In `password_reset.html` there might be something like `{% url 'foo' bar.id %}` which would cause this error to happen as well.

Comment: shouldn't it return PasswordResetForm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask specifically about "determining which arguments are missing", but should be irrelevant to your error.

Your error message states that it can't find any URL patterns matching the name "homepage", *before attempting any argument matching*. Therefore no URLs exist named "homepage" in your setup. If it was an argument mismatch, you'd see a list of named URLs in the error such as "tried X urls."

Either define a URL named home in your URLConf `url(r'^home/$', 'home_view', name="homepage")` or find the location that is calling `reverse('homepage')` and remove it. You will find this information in your traceback.

Comment: It might also be a url tag, such as `{% url 'homepage' %}`, instead of a direct call to reverse.

Comment: figured it out ... it was just problem with url i was sending requst to , i missed some part of it